# bulkTransfer doesn't work as expected. Why and how to work around it?

Tags: java, android, usb, android-service

I have a service that opens a device, sends data to it and then receives the answers from that device, all is fine but tests show some weird results. I am sending the commands and getting the answers in different threads if it matters.

This is the thread that handles receiving.

```
public void receiveThread() throws Exception{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[80];
    int i;
    while(true)
    {
        if((USBint != null) && (USBendIn != null))
        {
            i = USBcon.bulkTransfer(USBendIn, buffer, 2, 1);
            if(i > 0)
            {
                String s2 = new String(buffer);
                String s1 = bytesToHex(buffer);
                showToast("data received (" + i + ") :\n" + s1 + "\n" + s2);
            }
        }
        Thread.sleep(20);
    }
}
```

In `onStartCommand` I set USBcon and USBendIn. One is the connection and the other is the endpoint with IN direction.

The attention is on the line `i = USBcon.bulkTransfer(USBendIn, buffer, 2, 1);`
I've tried different variations of the parameters for length and timeout and they all give out the exact same result.
`USBcon.bulkTransfer(USBendIn, buffer, 2, 3000);` //this is supposed to wait for 2 bytes and wait for them for about 3 seconds. If 2 bytes are received before these 3 seconds the function should return 2 and receive just those 2 bytes.

`USBcon.bulkTransfer(USBendIn, buffer, 100, 3000);` //this is supposed to wait for 100 bytes and wait for them for about 3 seconds and if after 3 seconds there are some bytes received (less than 100) it should return this number.

`USBcon.bulkTransfer(USBendIn, buffer, 2, 1);` //this is supposed to wait for 2 bytes and wait for them for about 1 millisecond. If nothing gets in for 1ms it should return 0.

I even tried this `i = USBcon.bulkTransfer(USBendIn, buffer, 10, -20);` Guess negative timeouts are also acceptable

Those 4 examples all did the same exact thing. I receive some bytes in equal intervals with random length. The whole message I should receive is 24 bytes and I sometimes get it in 3 parts (example : 1 byte + 8 bytes + 15 bytes) and sometimes I get them all at once. They are put in the buffer even when I've stated I want to receive just 2 bytes. This shows errors in the length parameter. The timeout doesn't work either. Whatever I write as a timeout the function returns after some time (can't tell how much) regardless of the number of bytes received. Even negative times did the same. Even `Integer.MAX_VALUE` with 240 as length did the same (it receives 24 bytes every 3 seconds or so => it should have waited almost half a minute, it didn't).

The only 2 times this function acted differently was when I entered 0 as length. 2-3 seconds after the service has started the tablet reboots itself. Putting a negative length did nothing though, no reboot and no data received.

So.. what is going on ? It is not that big of a problem for my service but I don't like when I can't trust system functions. Makes me wonder what else will not work properly.

Comment: If you're expecting 24 bytes, then why not just ask for all 24? Typically when I've worked on a protocol I treat it as such, send command, ask for response. When I have used a read thread it has been when I either have streaming, or undefined data coming in. In this case you should simply always post an outstanding read for the max amount of data possible. Then as this data comes in put it in to a buffer. Your main thread can then pull data from your buffer as needed.

Comment: I get 24 bytes for this one particular command I am doing tests with. And there are times when data could be received unexpectedly. Anyway, whatever I do I won't change the fact that the function just ignores those 2 parameters (or completely crashes if it does.

Comment: The nature of USB is that the host initiates the transfers. So when you issue a bulkTransfer you are saying you are expecting some data. It's up to you to know how much you should receive, and if it is unknown it's why a continuous reader is preferred. I don't think the UsbConnection will hold the data for you, using bulkTransfer on an IN endpoint will issue an IN packet request to the device and it'll give you as much data as it has to give at that time. In my opinion the bottom line is either ask for the amount of data you are expecting, or setup a continuous reader.

Comment: Even if I know exactly how many bytes I am expecting and enter it as a parameter (length) It still does the same thing. I get random number of packets with random length that add upto what I am expecting. Giving the function a high timeout value one would expect the function to wait that much time before returning packets that are smaller than the expected length.